# Which ML model is better?

Tags: machine-learning, data-science

I have built two ML models with the following roc_auc_score

Model 1
Training score - 95%
Test score - 74%

Model 2
Training score - 78%
Test score - 74%

It is high likely that model 1 is trying to overfit but test score is same in both cases. So, which of these two is a better performing one?

Comment: my suggestion is repeat the training and testing for more times, and compare the avarages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume this is a hypothetical question where all other conditions are equal. In this case, I would argue with occam's razor and declare the simpler model (probably model 2) the winner.

In practice other factors might be important too. For example have you extensively tuned hyperparameters to get to Model 2 and thus overfit to the test data?

Comment: I didn't understand what you mean by overfitting test data. I did basic tuning to get parameters for lightgbm and random forest on CV error. So, it should actually help to decrease overfitting?

Comment: You have to be aware that each time you tune your parameters to improve your test score, you will adapt your model for good performance on the test dataset. When you do this often you will build a model that might overfit to your test data. That is exactly the reason why you usually have an additional validation dataset. You train on your training data and evaluate the resulting model on the validation data. Then you adapt your hyperparameters and train again until you are happy. Only when you are done you evaluate the final model on the test data.

Answer (score 0):

Without any further information, I would agree that your first model does appear to be overfit.  Other than that, both models conceptually have "learned" about the behavior of the underlying real world training data with a similar level of accuracy, as given by the identical test scores.

But because the first model is overfit, it means that the first model also has possibly incorporated noise from the training data.  This additional information won't help the model, and might actually hurt with making new predictions.

So, I would lean towards using the second model, if I had to choose one of the two.

Answer (score 0):

In general it is hard to give a concrete answer without getting insight in the use case, the problem to be sovled and the model and training strategy you have chosen. 
However, perhaps a differentiation between errors might help:

**Bayes Error**: This the theoretically lowest possible error a classifier might reach

**Human Error**: Classification error exhibited by a human solving the task.

**Avoidable Bias**: Difference between the human/bias error and the error exhibited by your model evaluated on the training set.

**Avoidable Variace**: Error difference between the test error and the training error

So in your case, it seems at the first sight that model 1 is overfitting when compared to model 2 since it has a lower variance. **When** compared. That does not mean model 1 is better, it depends. I would advice you to:

- Take a closer look at your available data: what is the distribution of the data? How does it differ from the possible upcoming data where the model is implemented?
- Further implement training techniques on model 1 to see if you can reduce the test error: data augmentation (relative to the task), weights regularization, dropout,  etc.

If you have already extensively performed this, then I would analyze performance/computation cost of both models (which one is faster/lighter) and as @saibot suggested, go with the simpler one (the one that consumes less ressources) (occams razer).

Remember, goal is not necessary to get your test error equal to the training error. It is actually to get your test error as close as possible to the bias error.